# Slide Drawer for android with image

Tags: android

How can we implement a slider like SimonVT with an image view so that the user will know about the drawer in android.Any other library will also do.

Comment: @anyone why a -2 point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use this slider:

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer

I Hope this help you

Comment: thanks for the answer but https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel helped me out

Comment: welcome
please rate my answer